# Is there any elegant method in Ruby to convert a number to an array of digits

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, fixnum

For number n, I could only think of

```
array_of_digits = n.to_s.split('').map(&:to_i)
```

Is there any more elegant method?

Comment: @itdoesntwork's `each_byte` method is interesting, but I think most Rubiests would go with what you have, though I think `string_of_digits = n.to_s.each_char.map(&:to_i)` is a small improvement because it doesn't create an intermediate array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not more elegant, but faster:

```
def digits(n)
  (0..Math.log10(n).to_i).map { |dp| n / 10 ** dp % 10 }.reverse
end
```

Another fast one I just found (fastest)

```
def digits(n)
  n.to_s.each_byte.map { |x| x - 48 }
end
```

Benchmarks:

```
            user     system      total        real
Split map  0.410000   0.000000   0.410000 (  0.412397)
chars      0.100000   0.010000   0.110000 (  0.104450)
each byte  0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.068171)
Numerical  0.100000   0.000000   0.100000 (  0.101828)
```

The code for benchmarking is here, by the way: https://gist.github.com/sid-code/9ad26dc4b509bfb86810

Comment: I was thinking split was slow too . . . want to compare with `n.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i)` ?

Comment: Yeah, I'd go for the chars one, it's fast and elegant, best of both worlds.

Comment: Numerical gives you some insight though (I expect `Fixnum#to_s` has something similar internally). Good answer either way.